# CASE statement in WHERE clause of SQL query. A little complicated with COUNT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, clause

This is in sql server 2005. I have two tables: `customers` and `orders`. There's a stored procedure that has a parameter `minimumorders` (0 or great than zero are possible values). I want to avoid an `IF ELSE` block like above and go with a `CASE` statement. Is there a way I can use a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause to avoid the `IF ELSE` block in the code? At the moment 5 lines on both the `IF` & `ELSE` blocks are repeated. I dont want them repeating. I am looking forward for a query like the following.

```
CREATE PROC STOREDPROC1
@MinimumOrders  INT AS IF @MinimumOrders = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMERID 
        , (SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID) AS ORDERS
        FROM CUSTOMER C
ENDELSE IF @MinimumOrders = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMERID 
        , (SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID) AS ORDERS
        FROM CUSTOMER C
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID) > 0
END
```

I need some `CASE` statement like the following. it does not work for me unfortunately.

```
-------------------- 12/20/2011 -- 11:52:34 AM -- Tuesday -------------------- 
    SELECT 
        CUSTOMERID 
        , (SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID) AS ORDERS
        FROM CUSTOMER C
        AND C.customerid=
            CASE @MiniumOrders
                WHEN 0 THEN C.CustomerID
                WHEN 1 THEN 
                    CASE  ( Select COUNT(O.CustomerID) FROM Orders O where O.Customerid = C.customerid    ) 
                        WHEN 0 THEN 0   -- customer id = 0 means no match
                            ELSE C.CustomerID
                    END 
                END 
        -------------------- 12/20/2011 -- 11:52:34 AM -- Tuesday --------------------
```

Comment: All these sub-queries will make this run tremendously slow with any large amount of data. Consider refactoring using some joins

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a join and a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT
    C.Customer_ID,
    COUNT(O.Customer_ID) AS Orders
FROM
    Customers C
    LEFT JOIN Orders O
        ON C.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
GROUP BY C.Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(O.Customer_ID) > @MinimumOrders
```

Comment: Basically, yes, but `>` should be `>=`. Also, the OP's query would return `0` in case of no orders while yours would show `NULL` (which is easily fixed if necessary, of course).

Comment: thank you simon for answering. I can't have group by in my real case because there are 5 other columns in the select statement which cannot go through an aggregation due to the group by at the bottom. Is there a CASE SELECT option as I requested originally? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a windowed `COUNT` clause. Since I don't have all the details on your situation, I've included an entire test case. The part you care about is the `SELECT` at the bottom.

```
DECLARE @Cust TABLE (
    CustID INT
)

DECLARE @Ord TABLE (
    OrdID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    CustID INT,
    Qty INT,
    Price MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @Cust 
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)

INSERT INTO @Ord
VALUES
(1, 5, 5.55),
(2,3,3.33),
(2,4,3.22),
(3,4,1.23),
(3,5,5.66),
(3,7,1.22)

DECLARE @MinimumOrders INT = 0

SELECT
    C.CustID,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(O.OrdID) OVER(PARTITION BY C.CustID) > @MinimumOrders THEN COUNT(O.OrdID) OVER(PARTITION BY C.CustID)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Orders,
    O.Qty,
    O.Price
FROM
    @Cust C
    LEFT JOIN @Ord O
        ON C.CustID = O.CustID
```